# I there an elegant way to re-assign deconstructed object values using ESNext

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, ecmascript-2021

Lets say we have an object with some values

```js
const objectWithSomeValues = {
    numbers: 12345,
    word: 'hello',
    valueIDontWantToBeDeconstructed: [1,2,3,4,{}, null]
}
```

And somewhere else in the code I'm deconstructing this object

```js
const someNewObject = {}
const { numbers, word } = objectWithSomeValues 
/* and reassigning them to another */
someNewObject.numbers = numbers
someNewObject.word = word
```

Is there more elegant way to reassign those values to this object, maybe there is a one-liner that

Answer (score 2):

List the `valueIDontWantToBeDeconstructed` and omit the others, and use rest syntax to collect those others into their own object.

```js
const objectWithSomeValues = {
    numbers: 12345,
    word: 'hello',
    valueIDontWantToBeDeconstructed: [1,2,3,4,{}, null]
};
const { valueIDontWantToBeDeconstructed, ...newObj } = objectWithSomeValues;
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
const { numbers, word } = objectWithSomeValues;

const someNewObject = { numbers, word };

console.log(someNewObject); // { numbers: 12345, word: 'hello' }
```

Alternatively,

```js
const someNewObject = {}
const { numbers, word } = objectWithSomeValues
Object.assign(someNewObject, {numbers, word});

console.log(someNewObject); // { numbers: 12345, word: 'hello' }
```